# Why this runs in the same time as the secvential version?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the folowing code:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for private(dot,sum,c,cc)
   for(r=0;r<rows;r++){

       for(c=0;c<cols;c++){
       dot = 0.0;
       sum = 0.0;

       for(cc=(-center);cc<=center;cc++){
        if(((c+cc) >= 0) && ((c+cc) < cols)){
           dot += (float)image[r*cols+(c+cc)] * kernel[center+cc];
           sum += kernel[center+cc];
        }
     }
     tempim[r*cols+c] = dot/sum;
  }
}
```

This code runs with the same speed as secvential version. What i do wrong? The rows , col values are like 4000+ and center something near 10-30.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but have you told your compiler to work with OpenMP?

Answer (score 0):

You could use profiling tools to check how many threads it uses actually. If it is single thread, you could check

- if the OpenMP support is enabled in for compile options
- if environment variables or OpenMP APIs have disabled multi-threading, i.e, `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, `OMP_DYNAMIC`, `omp_set_num_threads()`, ...